# I have an issue with my Ruby method I am trying to create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to execute the following code and I am not getting the response I want. I want set the answer to children in the client details hash.  I am pretty sure its because I have a get.chomp in my children method but I am not sure that I can set that response to an integer so I can shovel it into my hash.

```
# Get following details from client:
# name
# age
# number of children
# decor theme
# handicap
# if handicap ask if they would like wheelchair ramp or elevator.
# Program should also:
# Print the hash back to screen when designer answers all questions
# Give the user the option to update a key. Exit if user says "n." If      user enters "key," program should ask for new key value and update key.   (Strings have methods to turn them into symbols.)
# Print latest version of hash, exit


def children(response)
 until response == "y" || response == "n"
      puts "Invalid response, Please enter Y/N only!"
      response = gets.chomp.downcase
     end
      if response == "y"
        puts "How many children do you have?"
        number_of_children = gets.chomp.to_i
       else response == "n"
        number_of_children = 0
       end
end




client_details = {}

# ---- Driver Code ----

puts  "Welcome to the Client Information Form!"

# ---- get the user name ----
puts "Please enter the Clients Full Name:"
client_details[:name] = gets.chomp
# ---- get the user age ----
puts "Please enter #{client_details[:name]} age:"
client_details[:age] = gets.chomp.to_i
# ---- find out if the user has children ----
puts "Does #{client_details[:name]} have any children? (Please enter Y/N only)"
children_input = gets.chomp.downcase.to_s
children(children_input)



client_details[:children] = children(children_input)
p client_details
```

Here is what happens when I run the code:

```
'Welcome to the Client Information Form!
Please enter the Clients Full Name:
Art V
Please enter Art V age:
55
Does Art V have any children? (Please enter Y/N only)
y
How many children do you have?
8
How many children do you have?
8
{:name=>"Art V", :age=>55, :children=>8}
```

Comment: Show us the error you are getting, this will help us to diagnose the problem and propose a solution. Without that, all we can do is guess.

Comment: in the meantime, you will have a problem with this statement        `else number_of_children == "n"` the sytax doesn't follow. "else" should be standalone, no condition, or you can use if CONDITION ~ elsif CONDITION ~ else DEFAULTACTION. see [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/ruby/ruby-if-else-if-command-syntax/) for IF-ELSIF-ELSE

Comment: @CaptainChaos It's not an error I apologize, it just ask the question twice: ---------- Welcome to the Client Information Form!
Please enter the Clients Full Name:
Art V
Please enter Art V age:
55
Does Art V have any children? (Please enter Y/N only)
y
How many children do you have?
8
How many children do you have?
8
{:name=>"Art V", :age=>55, :children=>8}

Comment: @halfer can you offer any advice to help?

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean, not an error, but an unexpected response. Next time, be explicit as to the problem (you got the question "how many children..." multiple times)

Comment: @CaptainChaos I will again this is all new to me but thanks for the help.

Comment: You are most welcome, keep learning and keep asking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you get duplicated output is that you are calling the `children` method twice:

```
# this is the first time here
children_input = gets.chomp.downcase.to_s
children(children_input)

# and this is the second time here
client_details[:children] = children(children_input)
```

If you want to only call it once, then you need to save/store the return-value eg:

```
children_input = gets.chomp.downcase.to_s
num_children = children(children_input)
client_details[:children] = num_children
```